# What is the use case of IntersectionObserver?

Tags: javascript, html

I just found about new [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) on mozilla dev. I am going through it. It says that:

> The Intersection Observer API allows you to configure a callback that
>   is called whenever one item, called a target, intersects either the
>   device viewport or a specified element; for the purpose of this API,
>   the root element.

And it explains with following code snippet:

```
var options = {
    root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'),
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0
}
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
    /* Content excerpted, shown below */ 
};
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

I want to know it's use case. Doc only talks about how it can be used. It does explain in where it can be used. Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using IntersectionObserver and I pretty much love it.

One use case can be lazy loading images in your website, optimising your website payload to perform only the image fetch's user needs to see at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use cases

– It gives a smooth scrolling experience to the user

-Optimize bandwidth

– Lazy-loading of images or other elements as the page is scrolled

Adjust rootmargin -

If rootMargin is 400px means the callback will be called even from a distace of 400px, in other words, it means, even when there are html element with height 400px yet to be scrolled down the callback will be triggered.
[image]

You can find a good resource on [What is Intersection Observer & How to implement it here](https://qwertycod.com/what-is-intersection-observer-how-to-implement-it/)